# TryParse() - Why does this code return 0, shouldn't the result be -1?

Tags: c#, .net, console, tryparse

See the following code:

```
string test = "";
int output = -1;

if (int.TryParse(test, out output))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Parsed");
}

Console.WriteLine(output);
```

When `TryParse()` fails, shouldn't the block be skipped over, `Console.WriteLine("Parsed")` not called and the value of `output` be the same (-1)?

It's returning `0`

Comment: You should use the `output` only inside the `if` because it is only inside it that you know that the parsing succeeded.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The implementation of `TryParse` **has** to default the `out` parameter before returning otherwise it won't compile - ***regardless*** of whether you have initialised the `out` parameter from the calling side. This is the case for *any* method with `out` parameters and is not specific to `TryParse`.

The people who coded it chose to [default the parameter to zero](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx) when the parsing fails.

The important part is you should not think that any `out` parameter methods will honour the original value of the `out` parameter when it is passed in. In fact, it can *never* honour the parameter as the compiler will report:

> use of unassigned out parameter 'blah'

If you attempt to use the parameter value before assigning to it inside the method. So you can actually guarantee that any value you assign and give to as an `out` parameter will be ignored / overwritten.

Comment: Thanks, this makes perfect sense now although it's very misleading at first glance.

Comment: @Duane Indeed it can be, but it all stems off the usage of `out` parameters - other than the value chosen as the default, nothing here is specific to `TryParse`.

Answer (score 15):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx):

> When this method returns, contains the 32-bit signed integer value equivalent to the number contained in string, if the conversion succeeded, **or `zero` if the conversion failed.**

Answer (score 2):

if it fails it will `return false` and the code in the if statement won't be executed.

In the case the conversion fails it will also retun `0` that's why `output=0`

Answer (score 2):

In C#, `out` parameters have to be assigned to and cannot be initially read from. (When a method starts, the `out` parameters are treated like uninitialized variables.)

Therefore, the previous value of `output` is irrelevant. It had to be overwritten by the people who wrote the `TryParse` method, otherwise it could not have been compiled.

At the same time, the `TryParse` method has no access to the previous value of `output`. Therefore, some value has to be chosen. In this case, [the developers chose `0`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx).